# page would render without any css file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm having an issue with an EJS file not rendering as expected. I'm using ExpressJS. When the user put a name of a product at add-product end point i redirect him to the home page, the page would render without any css file like this :
[home page before the css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFXXP.png)

after reload the page i get the desired template:
[the desired page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eORKe.png)

Product Names are in json file, so i used the fs.promises modules

My Controllers are :

```
const Product = require('../models/product')
exports.getAddProducts=(req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('add-product',{pageTitle: 'Add Product', path:'/admin/add-product'});
}
exports.postAddProducts=(req,res,next)=>{
    const product = new Product(req.body.title);
     product.save();
    res.redirect('/');
}
exports.getProducts=async (req,res,next)=>{
    let products=[];
    try {
        products = await Product.fetchAll();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    res.render('shop',{products ,path:'/' ,pageTitle:'Shop'})
}
```

the my Modules is

```
module.exports = class Product{
    constructor(title){
        this.title=title;
    }
    async save(){
        const p = path.join(rootDir,'data','products.json')
        try {
            const fileContent = await fs.readFile(p)
            let products = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(fileContent).toString())
                products.push(this)
                await fs.writeFile(p,JSON.stringify(products))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return [];
        }
    }
    static async fetchAll(){
        const p = path.join(rootDir,'data','products.json')
        try {
            const fileContent = await fs.readFile(p)
            return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(fileContent).toString())
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

and my main app go like this

```
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views','views')

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
// app.use(express.static('public'))


app.use('/admin',adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes)
//app.use(userRoutes);

//handle 404 page
app.use('/',errorController.get404)

app.listen(3000,()=>{console.log('server up to date: ')
})
```